# Syntax highlighting not working from QMainWindow

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt4

I'm trying to implement syntax highlighting using PyQt4. The examples I've tried work fine, but as soon as I work it into an application the highlighting stops working.

I've created a minimal example to recreate the issue below. I've removed all the regex except for the comment one: lines starting in # should be bold and green:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
class Highlighter(QtGui.QSyntaxHighlighter):
    def __init__(self, document):
        QtGui.QSyntaxHighlighter.__init__(self, document)
        rules = []
        style = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        style.setForeground(QtGui.QColor('darkGreen'))
        style.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Bold)
        rules.append((r'#[^\n]*', style))
        self._rules = [(QtCore.QRegExp(pat), fmt) for (pat, fmt) in rules]
    def highlightBlock(self, text):
        for (pattern, style) in self._rules:
            i = pattern.indexIn(text, 0)
            while i >= 0:
                n = pattern.matchedLength()
                self.setFormat(i, n, style)
                i = pattern.indexIn(text, i + n)
        self.setCurrentBlockState(0)
```

The highlighter works fine if I use it like this:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
editor = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit()
highlight = Highlighter(editor.document())
editor.show()
app.exec_()
```

But fails when I use it in a QMainWindow, like this:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        editor = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit()
        highlighter = Highlighter(editor.document())
        self.setCentralWidget(editor)
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

thanks,
  Michael

Comment: Are you using the regex's from the example? If not have you tested them with something like http://www.regexr.com/?

Comment: Thanks! Haven't tried alternative regex's, but if you look at the bottom of the example you see it works fine when run directly, it only stops working when you embed the editor widget in a QMainWindow. That suggests the regex is fine. I've updated the question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the highlighter. So just do:

```
    self.highlighter = Highlighter(editor.document())
```

**EDIT**:

To be more precise: you need to keep a reference to the *python* part of your `QSyntaxHighlighter` subclass. The parent object passed to the constructor will take ownership of the highlighter, but Qt obviously won't automatically manage the python part as well.

Here's the real difference:

```
    print(repr(self.editor.document().children())) ...

    # without keeping a reference
    [<PyQt4.QtGui.QPlainTextDocumentLayout object at 0x7f8590909b88>
     <PyQt4.QtGui.QSyntaxHighlighter object at 0x7f8590909c18>]

    # with a reference
    [<PyQt4.QtGui.QPlainTextDocumentLayout object at 0x7f56b7898c18>,
     <__main__.Highlighter object at 0x7f56b7898a68>]
```

So your reimplemented `highlightBlock` function will be invisible to Qt unless you keep a reference.

Comment: Thank you _so_ much! This was driving me absolutely mental. (It works in PySide, I discovered, apparently there someone makes a reference back...)

Comment: So this is just a garbage collection issue?

Comment: @MichaelClerx. Not exactly: see my updated answer. There are clearly differences between PySide and PyQt when it comes to keeping track of ownership and such like.

Comment: thank you so much! I would never ever be able to figure that out without this post!